Active Directory delegations are being re added after removing
We have a couple of Exchange groups that throws permissions on everything. Every time I try to remediate the permissions on privileged users or groups, it always gets added back instantly. Note that some users are in other groups that this Exchange group has (and should have) delegations over. So that makes me think it's a nesting/group membership issue. For instance, because I remove Exchange permissions over a Domain Admin, that Domain Admin is in another group that the Exchange group has permissions over.
I think this is the issue at least, it could be something else though. Let me know if anyone has any thought on how to fix this or if there are any other reasons this could be occurring.
EDIT: Another key thing I'm trying to figure out is how these Exchange groups are inheriting these permissions over all objects.

it always gets added back instantly
Sounds like you are encountering the normal "AdminSDHolder" process. What are you modifying, and how?

@GregAskew I'm modifying a member of Domain Admins to test this. If the AdminSDHolder process is what is doing this, how can I go around it?

What are you modifying?

@GregAskew I am removing permissions in the 'Security' tab of an exchange group over this domain admin

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/security-best-practices/appendix-c--protected-accounts-and-groups-in-active-directory
